# dealing with loops in javascript, only last item gets affected?

Tags: javascript, closures

Im working with the gm npm module that deals with image manipulation. and i have this code.

```
for(i=0;i < 4;i++){
    gm("www/img/" + image[i]).crop(550, 406, 0, 0).write(function(err) {
         console.log(this.outname + " created  ::  " + arguments[3]); //success
    });
}
```

this loop is meant to loop through the images array and crop each photo, but it only crops the last one. i think its something to do function invocation and callbacks, but not advanced yet for that level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    gm("www/img/" + image[i]).crop(550, 406, 0, 0).write(function(err) {
         console.log(this.outname + " created  ::  " + arguments[3]); //success
    });
  }).call(this, i);
}
```

otherwise the value of `i` will be 3 each time your callback is being invoked.

Comment: wont work. you need to lock the var

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now.

Comment: +1 For maintaining the original context `this` inside the anonymous function which is missing in Royi's answer as of now

Comment: arguments should also be kept. youre overriding them via `call`. look at my sample

Comment: how about if i want to pass two variables to the inner function(closure) so for example i and b

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a "closure" over the variable

Js has a **function** scope.

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    (function (a)
    {
        gm("www/img/" + image[a]).crop(550, 406, 0, 0).write(function (err)
        {
            console.log(this.outname + " created  ::  " + arguments[3]); //success
        });
    }).call(this,i)
}
```

or

```
that=this;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        (function (a)
        {
            gm("www/img/" + image[a]).crop(550, 406, 0, 0).write(function (err)
            {
                console.log(that.outname + " created  ::  " + arguments[3]); //success
            });
        })(i)
    }
```

edit :

Also - I would **also keep** a reference to the `arguments` since now , after IIFE - the arguments is changing.

you can keep your `arguments` via :

`var args= Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)`

example :

```
function g()

{
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        (function (a)
        {
           console.log(arguments); //huh ? arguments are not a,b,c !!! anymore
        })(i);
    }
}


g('a','b','c') // 0,1,2,3
```

so you do need to keep reference to the arguments cuz their changed after IIFE.

Comment: +1 Nice answer..Every JS beginner definitely comes across similar problem. I did too few days back :)

Comment: @blunderboy tnx - most important is to understand that JS has function scope. and that closure is merely a scope where inner function has access to it's parent scope' .

Comment: Exactly and you made the answer to the point.

Comment: One thing you have missed is the context of `this` in the anonymous function. You should use `var that = this` and use that inside the function or just use `call` or may be use `bind` method.

Comment: @blunderboy `this` in IIFE  is the global window. if you want to keep the outer IIFE scope for future using `this` then - `than` is the right way.

Comment: Exactly it is global window but looks like OP have a different context here of `this`.

Comment: @blunderboy ooop's didnt see `this`... editing

Comment: @blunderboy I believe arguments should also be handled. see below

Comment: Wow!! You made an excellent catch. I can't upvote twice man :(

Comment: Mods will throw both of us out for this off-topic conversation..Just saying :P

Comment: `Js has a function scope.`  Might be worth pointing out, modern JS has block scope too, with `let / const`..