# foreach only sends last xhr request

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea where users can enter multiple URLs which in return will be used for an API request.

The issue I run into is that only the last URLs API request gets captured (sometimes multiple times).

```
$('.start').on('click',function()
{
    var url_list = $("#url-list").val();
    var urls = url_list.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0, len = urls.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("i is "+i)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', urls[i], true);
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

        // send API request
        function processRequest() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I don't see exactly where I am doing something wrong, I might be blind to it or just don't know any better. Any help would be appreciated. PS. fairly new to making API requests.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for element selection, but not for the AJAX request… that's really one of the only benefits it offers.  Also, you're in a race condition, you need a closure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dealing with loops in javascript, only last item gets affected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438002/dealing-with-loops-in-javascript-only-last-item-gets-affected)

Comment: @vol7ron thanks for the note. The only reason I didn't is because I read only that just for one simple GET request it would be on overkill. After re-reading the article I realized that only using the jQuery library for one request is on overkill but not if you already use it. Thanks!

Comment: Correct, if you're going to load it, you might as well use it, unless you really need performance outside of what it offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Welcome to closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438002/dealing-with-loops-in-javascript-only-last-item-gets-affected).

The problems here are:

- The loop could be finished before the first request starts, so it takes the last url in the array
- In the callback you are referencing the same `xhr` object

You can try one of the different solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1521064).

Replacing `xhr` with `this` in the callback is the fastest fix:

```
function processRequest() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdpv24f9) for a running example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I put `(function (i) { }` inside the loop and it started working correctly.

Comment: *`urls[i]`* - No, the `i` variable is only used by synchronous code that creates the requests, there is no code using it after the loop has completed. I think the real problem is similar though: the ready state change handler uses the `xhr` variable.

Comment: @ChrisPalmerBreuer instead of creating an anonymous function, it might be better to use `bind()`

Answer (score -1):

You could update your code like this

```
var requestIndex = 0;
var urls = [];

$('.start').on('click',function()
{
    // Reset request index
    requestIndex = 0;

    var url_list = $("#url-list").val();
    urls = url_list.split("\n");

    // Send Http request    
    sendRequest(urls, requestIndex);

});

// Send Http request
function sendRequest(urls, index) {

    // Send API request 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', urls[index], true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
    xhr.send();

}

// Process API request
function processRequest(e) {

    if (e.target.readyState == 4 && e.target.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
        console.log(response);
    }

    requestIndex++;
    if (requestIndex < urls.length) {
       sendRequest(urls, requestIndex);
    }

}
```

Comment: there are no problems in sending multiple requests at once. and previous requests are not canceled.